# Old cartoon show about short horror stories

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror, cartoon

I've been trying to remember the name of an old cartoon show I used to watch a bit over ten years ago. It used to air late at night, I think around midnight. But I can't remember the channel, it might have been Cartoon Network but I'm not sure.

Each episode focused on a different story, but all of those stories where horror related. I especially remember 3 such episodes:

- A young girl sees a cat and follows him. The cat ends up leading her towards a boat, which belongs to Death. Using her wits, she manages to trick Death by gluing its hand to the boat. She takes his book, which contains the date at which each person in the world will die, and starts ripping off page by page until Death accepted to strike a deal with her, allowing her to live for another 100 years.
- A young girl goes roller skating with one of her friends. I don't exactly remember how, but she stumbles upon the garden of an old woman, in which there are roses. She takes one of those roses, and she finds out that the rose is able to grant her any wish she wants. But after a while she realize that the rose consumes her own life for each wish. She then decides to return the rose by putting it back on its tree.
- A young kid is playing with his kite, from what I remember in a town close to the sea, and it was raining quite a bit. His kite ends up getting caught in the wind and crashes down in a cemetery, which disturbs the slumber of one of those buried here. I remember the undead in question was quite tall, and either had fish, or smelled like fish. The kid decides to give a new shirt to the undead, and bring him back to his home to do so. I also remember that, whenever the undead appeared, fog appeared together with him.

I'm pretty sure there were more episodes than this, but it's all I can remember.

---

It is not *Grizzly Tales* or *Freaky Stories*.

Comment: If it were late and on Cartoon Network, it’d likely be on Adult Swim, so that could be a more useful search term.

Answer (score 1):

There was a period at the end of 90s when "scary" cartoons were quite common.

One could be [*Tales from the Cryptkeeper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Cryptkeeper) and the following series, New Tales from the Cryptkeeper

From Wikipedia:

> *Tales from the Cryptkeeper* is an animated horror children's series made by Nelvana. It was shown on YTV in Canada and on ABC in the United States. In Canada, it still airs re-runs near Halloween on Teletoon. It was based on the 1950s EC Comics series Tales from the Crypt, and the live-action television show, of the same name, which aired concurrently on HBO. Being aimed at children, Tales from the Cryptkeeper was significantly milder than its live-action HBO counterpart and all blood and gore were completely omitted in order to target the audience.
>
> The series was cancelled on December 10, 1994. In 1999, the show returned to the air as *New Tales from the Cryptkeeper*. The animation was different from that of the previous episodes and it switched over to Teletoon in Canada, and also switched to CBS in the United States.
>
> The show details the Cryptkeeper telling different horror stories to the viewers, each with a lesson to be learned.

This is a picture of the Cryptkeeper

[image]

and another picture from the following season

[image]